# Given a number m with n digits, find the sum of all permutations of m with exactly n digits

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, permutations

I've been struggling to find this solution. So far, I know the sum of all permutations of $m$, for example $123$, is $2!(1+2+3)(111) = 1332$.

Also I got that the number of permutations of $m$ with no leading zeros is: $$\frac{(n-z)(n-1)!}{r}$$ where $z$ is the number of zeros in $m$, and $r$ is all the factorials of repeated digits. For example, the previous formula applied to the number $12220$ would be: $$\frac{4 \times 4!}{3!} = 16$$

As far as I know the solution consists in the sum of all permutations with no leading zeros, eliminating the repeated permutations. Could you please help me by giving ideas, comments, etc.?

The description of this problem is [here](http://coj.uci.cu/24h/problem.xhtml?pid=2855).

Comment: A hint could be to use symmetricity. Each digit will occur in each position in the number equally number of times (disregarding multiplicity). Wait you already state that in the beginning for 123. What is the real question then?

Comment: My question is how to do it with numbers with repeated digits such as 12220 or 1000, how do I count how many times a digit occurs in each position in those cases?